# The element type 'List<Text>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, widget

```dart
   body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
                builder: (context,snapshot){
                  List<Widget> messageWidgets = [];
                  if(snapshot.hasData){
                    final messages = snapshot.data?.docs;

                    for(var message in messages!){
                     final messageText = message.get('text');
                     final messageSender = message.get('sender');
                     final messageWidget = Text('$messageText from $messageSender');
                     messageWidgets.add(messageWidget);

                    }

                  }
                  return Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      messageWidgets
                    ],
                  );
                }
            ),
            Container(
              decoration: kMessageContainerDecoration,
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        //Do something with the user input.
                        message = value;
                      },
                      decoration: kMessageTextFieldDecoration,
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      //Implement send functionality.
                      _firestore.collection('messages').add({
                       'sender':loggedInUser.email,
                        'text':message
                      });
                    },
                    child: const Text(
                      'Send',
                      style: kSendButtonTextStyle,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: `stream: _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots(),` - Please don't build your stream in the stream parameter of a StreamBuilder..

Answer (score 0):

You can directly pass widget

```dart
children: messageWidgets,
```

Or

```dart
children: <Widget>[...messageWidgets],
```

`[messageWidgets]` means `List<List<Widget>>` where it expects `List<Widget>`

Comment: Glad to help, you can explore more on [dart-core](https://api.dart.dev/be/180791/dart-core/List-class.html)